# Microsoft Word 2010 docm file does not print

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

I have a Microsoft Word 2010 file (saved as `abcd.docm`) that does not print. I reinstalled the printer driver and tried to print from other programs (Notepad, WordPad, etc.,) and they all *do* print.

I'm guessing it's because of the `.docm` extension that something broke. I've circumvented the problem by saving the file as a `.pdf` and printing that, but this is impractical as I've got to edit the Word file every so often.

So, how can I force the file to print?

---

PS: I must keep the `.docm` extension for the Word file as the document contains lots of linked boxes (content control drop-down lists that are interlinked all over the place).

---

Additional details:

- I've tried opening the file and printing it in Word 2013. Same problem occurs (doesn't print).
- After clicking on `Print`, when focus returns to the document, the following message appears on the bar at the bottom (what is it called?) 'Word is repaginating abcd.docm. Press escape to cancel.' After that 'Word is preparing to background print the document'. I've tried letting it repaginate and tried canceling too but there's no difference. It still won't print.

---

EDIT:
I found the following code by clicking on the `Developer -> Visual basic` tab.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument
  If ContentControl.Title = "Classification" Then
    ContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Clear
    For i = 1 To .ContentControls.Count
      If Left(.ContentControls(i).Title, 5) = "Level" Then
        j = j + 1
        ContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add Text:=j & " - " & .ContentControls(i).Range.Text
      End If
    Next
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What actually happens when you print? DOCM files *should* be able to print fine.

Comment: The question title says `dotm`. The question body says `docm`. Which is correct?

Comment: @Jonno Usually when clicking on "print" the screen will revert to the document and a print preview window will pop up (that's because of my printer, which has this option). But in this case, there in no preview and an icon (a printer icon) shows up on the notification area on the taskbar; hovering my mouse pointer on it pops up a tooltip saying "0 documents pending for *name* ".
DavidPostill Sorry, there was a pending edit that was blocking my corrrections to the post.

Comment: Have you tried saving the same file as a .doc?  like in the answer i provided? You keep the original and you can now print it.

Comment: @K.Rmth I'm wondering if you have a macro somehow conflicting with printing. Can you create a new (blank, empty) `.docm` document and try and print that?

Comment: Do you have more then one printer maybe it is trying to print on something else always a possibility.

Comment: Nope NetworkKingPin as I did what @Jonno suggested without modifying any print settings, and the blank `.docm` document printed fine.

Comment: @K.Rmth Can you add the macros you're using to your question?

Comment: The document doesn't have any macros (that I know of, seeing as `View -> Macros -> View macros` shows nothing. Also using the document inspector shows nothing in the category `Macros, Forms and ActiveX controls`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

Step 1
Press "**Ctrl**-O" in Microsoft Word and double-click the DOCM file to open it.

Step 2
Press "**File**" and then "**Save As**."

Step 3
Click the "**Save as Type**" drop-down menu and select "Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)."

Step 4
Click "**Save**" to save the file with same name, but with the DOC extension. Doing so keeps the original file and saves a DOC copy.

Now print the .doc and it will print.

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested but it still doesn't print.